# Add a new column to the elements of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list (input_m) containing other lists of numbers. I want to add a new column (zero) to each element of the list to have a final list (output_m):

```
input_m = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
output_m = [[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
```

I have tried with list comprehensions, but I don't get the output_m in the format I want. Here is the code:

```
def add_column(matrix):
    res = [[item,0] for item in matrix]
    return res

output_m = add_column(input_m)

output_m = [[[3, 2], 0], [[5, 1], 0], [[4, 7], 0]]
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: try `item.append(0)` inside the list comprehension

Comment: @Kamehameha, note `append()` does not return the list, so you would end up with `[None, None, None]`

Comment: @MartinEvans yep. `[item.append(0) for item in matrix]` would return `[None...]` but matrix value would have changed to - `[[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the list comprehension -

```
res = [[item,0] for item in matrix]
```

`item` is list, that is why you are getting the result as - `[[[3, 2], 0], [[5, 1], 0], [[4, 7], 0]]`

Try concatenation instead , Example -

```
def add_column(matrix):
    res = [item + [0] for item in matrix]
    return res
```

Comment: Maybe I shoud post this into a different question but, how would I translate your list comprehensions in a loop?

Comment: `res = []
for item in matrix: 
    res.append(item+[0])` ?